# Java, Refactoring case

Tags: java, refactoring

I was given exercise that I need to refactor several java projects.
Only those 2 left which I truly don't have an idea how to refactor.

csv.writer

```
public class CsvWriter {
public CsvWriter() {
}

public void write(String[][] lines) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
        writeLine(lines[i]);
}

private void writeLine(String[] fields) {
    if (fields.length == 0)
        System.out.println();
    else {
        writeField(fields[0]);

        for (int i = 1; i < fields.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(",");
            writeField(fields[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

private void writeField(String field) {
    if (field.indexOf(',') != -1 || field.indexOf('\"') != -1)
        writeQuoted(field);
    else
        System.out.print(field);
}

private void writeQuoted(String field) {
    System.out.print('\"');
    for (int i = 0; i < field.length(); i++) {
        char c = field.charAt(i);
        if (c == '\"')
            System.out.print("\"\"");
        else
            System.out.print(c);
    }
    System.out.print('\"');
}
}
```

csv.writertest

```
public class CsvWriterTest {

@Test
public void testWriter() {
    CsvWriter writer = new CsvWriter();
    String[][] lines = new String[][] {
            new String[] {},
            new String[] { "only one field" },
            new String[] { "two", "fields" },
            new String[] { "", "contents", "several words included" },
            new String[] { ",", "embedded , commas, included",
                    "trailing comma," },
            new String[] { "\"", "embedded \" quotes",
                    "multiple \"\"\" quotes\"\"" },
            new String[] { "mixed commas, and \"quotes\"", "simple field" } };

    // Expected:
    // -- (empty line)
    // only one field
    // two,fields
    // ,contents,several words included
    // ",","embedded , commas, included","trailing comma,"
    // """","embedded "" quotes","multiple """""" quotes"""""
    // "mixed commas, and ""quotes""",simple field

    writer.write(lines);
}
}
```

test

```
public class Configuration {
public int interval;

public int duration;

public int departure;

public void load(Properties props) throws ConfigurationException {
    String valueString;
    int value;

    valueString = props.getProperty("interval");
    if (valueString == null) {
        throw new ConfigurationException("monitor interval");
    }
    value = Integer.parseInt(valueString);
    if (value <= 0) {
        throw new ConfigurationException("monitor interval > 0");
    }
    interval = value;

    valueString = props.getProperty("duration");
    if (valueString == null) {
        throw new ConfigurationException("duration");
    }
    value = Integer.parseInt(valueString);
    if (value <= 0) {
        throw new ConfigurationException("duration > 0");
    }
    if ((value % interval) != 0) {
        throw new ConfigurationException("duration % interval");
    }
    duration = value;

    valueString = props.getProperty("departure");
    if (valueString == null) {
        throw new ConfigurationException("departure offset");
    }
    value = Integer.parseInt(valueString);
    if (value <= 0) {
        throw new ConfigurationException("departure > 0");
    }
    if ((value % interval) != 0) {
        throw new ConfigurationException("departure % interval");
    }
    departure = value;
}
}


 public class ConfigurationException extends Exception {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public ConfigurationException() {
    super();
}

public ConfigurationException(String arg0) {
    super(arg0);
}

public ConfigurationException(String arg0, Throwable arg1) {
    super(arg0, arg1);
}

public ConfigurationException(Throwable arg0) {
    super(arg0);
}

}
```

configuration.test

```
public class ConfigurationTest{

@Test
public void testGoodInput() throws IOException {
    String data = "interval = 10\nduration = 100\ndeparture = 200\n";

    Properties input = loadInput(data);

    Configuration props = new Configuration();
    try {
        props.load(input);
    } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
        assertTrue(false);
        return;
    }

    assertEquals(props.interval, 10);
    assertEquals(props.duration, 100);
    assertEquals(props.departure, 200);
}
@Test
public void testNegativeValues() throws IOException {
    processBadInput("interval = -10\nduration = 100\ndeparture = 200\n");
    processBadInput("interval = 10\nduration = -100\ndeparture = 200\n");
    processBadInput("interval = 10\nduration = 100\ndeparture = -200\n");
}
@Test
public void testInvalidDuration() throws IOException {
    processBadInput("interval = 10\nduration = 99\ndeparture = 200\n");
}
@Test
public void testInvalidDeparture() throws IOException {
    processBadInput("interval = 10\nduration = 100\ndeparture = 199\n");
}
@Test
private void processBadInput(String data) throws IOException {
    Properties input = loadInput(data);

    boolean failed = false;
    Configuration props = new Configuration();
    try {
        props.load(input);
    } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
        failed = true;
    }

    assertTrue(failed);
}
@Test
private Properties loadInput(String data) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = new StringBufferInputStream(data);

    Properties input = new Properties();
    input.load(is);
    is.close();

    return input;
}
}
```

Comment: You need to describe your problem in a lot more detail. This is very vague. What specifically do you need help with? Also, this is a lot of code to dump.

Comment: what do you want to achieve ? What is the issue ?

Comment: As general im trying to remove every bad smells & refactor whole code & eliminate any bugs / mistakes and simplify code and optimize every fuctions / loops.

Comment: @Neleron do you expect someone to rewrite this code or maybe you need some advice?

Comment: @Andrey Cheboksarov 
Mostly advices, however both (advices / rewrite ) would work ( as I could learn how to do it well ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here some advice regarding the code.

**CsvWriter**

- The bad thing is that you print everything to System.out. It will be hard to test without mocks. Instead I suggest you to add field PrintStream which defines where all data will go.

  ```
  import java.io.PrintStream;

  public class CsvWriter {

  private final PrintStream printStream;

  public CsvWriter() {
      this.printStream = System.out;
  }

  public CsvWriter(PrintStream printStream) {
      this.printStream = printStream;
  }
  ...
  ```

You then write everything to this stream. This refactoring easy since you use replace function(Ctrl+R in IDEA). Here is the example how you do it.

```
private void writeField(String field) {
    if (field.indexOf(',') != -1 || field.indexOf('\"') != -1)
        writeQuoted(field);
    else
        printStream.print(field);
}
```

Others stuff seems ok in this class.

**CsvWriterTest**

- First thing first you don't check all logic in a single method. Make small methods with different kind of tests. It's ok to keep your current test though. Sometimes it's useful to check most of the logic in a complex scenario.
- Also pay attention to the names of the methods. Check [this](https://dzone.com/articles/7-popular-unit-test-naming)
- Obviously you test doesn't check the results. That's why we need this functionality with PrintStream. We can build a PrintStream on top of the instance of ByteArrayOutputStream. We then construct a string and check if the content is valid. Here is how you can easily check what was written

  ```
  public class CsvWriterTest {

  private ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  private PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(byteArrayOutputStream);

  @Test
  public void testWriter() {
      CsvWriter writer = new CsvWriter(printStream);
      ... old logic here ...
      writer.write(lines);

      String result = new String(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
      Assert.assertTrue(result.contains("two,fields"));
  ```

  **Configuration**
- Make fields private
- Make messages more concise

**ConfigurationException**
Seems good about serialVersionUID. This thing is needed for serialization/deserialization.

**ConfigurationTest**

- Do not use assertTrue(false/failed); Use Assert.fail(String) with some message which is understandable.

Tip: if you don't have much experience and need to refactor code like this, you may want to read some chapters of Effective Java 2nd edition by Joshua Bloch. The book is not so big so you can read it in a week and it has some rules how to write clean and understandable code.